# How do I get my button to perform an animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button

I have created an `@IBAction` function connecting my button in view controller to the main storyboard. The goal is to get my button to do a shake animation but I have no idea how to connect it. I get the error *Declaration is only valid at file scope* on the `extension UIButton {` line. Do I need to get rid of the extension? Move other lines around? How do I get the button to animate? There is more code below what is shown for having mapkit run do I need to create another class?

I have tried removing the extension altogether, renaming the name before the UIButton and channging UIButton() to the other names, tried looking at tutorials but nothin fits exactly what I have.

```
//button
@IBAction func diceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //shake button


    //shake
    extension UIButton {

        func buttonshake() {
            let shake = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            shake.duration = 0.1
            shake.repeatCount = 2
            shake.autoreverses = true

            let fromPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x - 5, y: center.y)
            let fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: fromPoint)

            let toPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + 5, y: center.y)
            let toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: toPoint)

            shake.fromValue = fromValue
            shake.toValue = toValue

            layer.add(shake, forKey: nil)

        }
    }

}
```

Error occurs on the line under //shake and nowhere else. It's all in the action of the button and I don't have another button anywhere in my code so I don't see anything that could be repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `extension` to the top level, out of any `func` or `class` definition.

The best practice is to create a new file, name it `UIButton+Shake.swift`, and put your extension into it.

Then, in the `IBAction`, just call `buttonshake`

---

UIButton+Shake.swift

```
extension UIButton {

    func buttonshake() {
        let shake = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        // And all the other stuff

        layer.add(shake, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

YourController.swift

```
class YourController : UIViewController {
    // ...
    @IBAction func diceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.buttonshake()
    }
}
```